# Connecting through pyodbc, strange error

Tags: python, sql-server, visual-studio-code, pyodbc

I'm getting the following error after running this:

```
  connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=xxxxx.xxxx.net;PORT=1443;DATABASE=xxx;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx')
cursor = connection.cursor()
SQLCommand = ("SELECT [Date]...FROM [dbo].[...]")
cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
results = cursor.fetchone()
connection.close
```

Error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: collate_byname::collate_byname failed to construct for C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C

Any ideas on how to remediate?

Comment: Try omitting `;PORT=1443` from the connection string since 1443 is the default port and Microsoft's ODBC drivers do not use a `PORT=` parameter anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the {ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server} which worked. Not sure why this is incompatible.